# Is a string parameter sent to PowerShell not really a string?

Tags: powershell

I am bit confused of the behaviour of the script below:

Test.ps1:

```
param(
    [array]$Value = $(throw "Give me a value")
)

Write-Host $Value 
$Value | Get-Member -MemberType Method
$Value.ToUpper()
```

Running the script:

```
PS C:\Temp> .\weird.ps1 test
TypeName: System.String
Name MemberType Definition
—- ———- ———-
…
ToUpper Method string ToUpper(), string ToUpper(System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
…
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn’t contain a method named ‘ToUpper’.
At C:\Temp\weird.ps1:6 char:15
+ $Value.ToUpper <<<< ()
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (ToUpper:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Why do I get a MethodNotFound exception? Get-Member clearly says it is a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's happening here is that the variable `$value` is typed to `Object[]` in the script.  The call to `Get-Member` works because you are piping the value into the function.  Hence instead of seeing the array it sees the values in the array which are indeed typed to `String`.  This can be viewed by using the following `Get-Member` call without piping

```
Get-Member -MemberType Method -InputObject $value
```

This is also why ToUpper correctly fails (it's an array not a `String`).

Answer (score 4):

When you pipe a collection of anything in powershell, it gets "unrolled" and sent one by one to the right hand side of the bar (pipe) character. This means that the *contents* of the array get sent to get-member. Get-member only accepts the first item sent to it, so it shows you the members of the string. Your parameter is of type `[array]`, so the parameter binder sets $value to an array of length 1, containing your string "test."

Example:

```
ps> @(1,"hello",3) | gm
... shows members of int32

ps> @("hello", 1, 3) | gm
... shows members of string
```

In order to see the members of an array when you pipe it, you should wrap it in another array, so it becomes the unrolled item:

```
ps> ,@("hello", 1, 3) | gm
... shows members of array
```

The leading comma "," creates a wrapping array.

-Oisin

Answer (score 2):

$Value is actually an array, because that is how you declare the parameter in your param block.